# Is it possible to force VS 2013 to use VS 2010 compiler for compiling?

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-c++, compiler-version

I want to wrap a library for python. Python is compiled with VS2010 and I have VS2013. Is it possible to force VS2013 to compile like VS2010?

PS. I have tried, unless the version of compiler that compiled python and the compiler that compiles the wrapper are the same it does not work.

PS. My python app has dependency to many other libraries and I can not recompile it with VS 2013

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can change the `Platform Toolset` option on the project's `General` property page. Note: you must have both VS2013 and VS2010 installed, along with the proper Windows SDKs.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ff770576(v=vs.110).aspx